# React-Intl depend on urls

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-intl

I have a multilanguage service and I want my locales to be dependent on the URL like:
https://example.com/en
https://example.com/de
etc.
What is the best practice to do that?

Comment: You can create a locale utils and add the logic to return the locale there. Then you can write a js code to parse the url, for example, and get it based on it and pass it to the intlProvider together with the messages.

Comment: @Periback I'm really sorry, do you have some code example?